# How to get the file directory for a custom cmdlet

Tags: powershell

The way our business is set up, our custom cmdlets are spread out across the network in several different larger files. We refer to these files in the usual "Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1"

Is there something I can run within Powershell to find where a cmdlet is running from instead of manually going through all the files referenced in "Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1" to find it?

E.g. if I have written a cmdlet called *Get-UserExpiry* and it is saved in *C:\User\Name\Documents\CustomCmds.ps1*, and I include that file path in Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1, is there a command I can use to find that file path if all I know is the cmdlet name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Get-Command` is what you need. That being said, depending on the command you are testing and the type of the command (external application, function, cmdlet, profile function), the command path won't always be assigned to the same property / subproperty.

Here's a way to get the path no matter where it is disclosed.

**Function definition**

Here we check the possible locations of the path based on the `Get-Command` result, filter out everything that is `$null` or empty and pick the first result we get.

```
Function Get-CommandLocation($Command) {
    $definition = (Get-Command -Name $Command)
    @(
        $definition.Module.Path
        $definition.Source
        $definition.ScriptBlock.File
    ) | Where-Object { $_ } | Select-Object -First 1
}
```

Examples

```
Get-CommandLocation Get-Item  # Native cmdlet
# Value obtained from (Get-Command -Name 'Get-Item').Module.Path
# Return C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\Microsoft.PowerShell.Management.psd1
 
Get-CommandLocation Edit-Profile # Custom profile function (Test with a function in your profile (if any))
# Value obtained from(Get-Command -Name 'Edit-Profile').ScriptBlock.File
# Return C:\Users\SagePourpre\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.VSCode_profile.ps1
 
Get-CommandLocation New-ExternalHelp # PlatyPS module downloaded from the gallery
# Value obtained from (Get-Command New-ExternalHelp).Module.Path
# Return C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\platyPS\0.14.2\platyPS.psm1

Get-CommandLocation -command cmd # External Program
# Value located in  (Get-Command -Name 'cmd').Source
# Return C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
```

Comment: @mklement0 I updated my function to work with external application. I also simplified the whole thing since in fact, everything needed is available through `Get-Command`. I don't understand the external script concern though. From my quick testing, I know Powershell load modules from path on-demand and `Get-Command` work fine but external scripts, paths or not, need to be loaded to be picked up by `Get-Command`, no ? In any cases, if the external script is imported in the current session, its location will be revealed through `Get-Item`, like the others scenario.

Comment: Nicely done, thanks for updating - that  should now cover all command types (except aliases, which would have to be resolved first). PowerShell treats external scripts - i.e., stand-alone `.ps1` files - like any other external program, in the sense that it automatically discovers them if present in a directory listed in `$env:PATH`(but irrespective of `$env:PATHEXT` on Windows / the executable permission bit on Unix), and reads and executes them on demand (no importing); the only difference to external programs is that it executes them _in-process_.